# How to display this entity in thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm writing simple task managment app in Spring boot. 
I've got entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "project_id")
    private Long projectId;
    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "task_id")
    private List<Task> task;
    // getters and setter omitted
```

I try to display this in Thymeleaf in that way:

```
<div th:each="project : ${projects}">
    <div th:text="${project.name}"></div>
        <div th:each="task : ${project.task}">
            <div th:text="${task.name}"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

It's shows only projects but I can't see my tasks. 
What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: if you use table instead of the div, is it work

Comment: No I didn't. It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

This probably happens because project.task is null, therefore there is no iteration. By default, attributes that include complex/custom (usually stored in a different table) objects are not selected from your database when you do a query on the parent object (lazy loading).

You can verify this by a simple check in your HTML, e.g.:

```
<p th:if="${project.task} == null">Task is indeed null</p>
```

Quick fix:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```